# How to add image path to database + associate images with albums?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am making a website with albums and images just to learn how to work with images. I am able to change the image names and upload them to image folder.

My issues are two:

(1) I don't know how to add the image path to database
(2) I don't know how to add a list of images to each album

I've spent a lot of time trying to find answers with no results.

```
public class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AlbumId")]
        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }

        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }

        public List<Image> Image { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(int id, Album album)
        {
            if (id != album.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var newFileName = string.Empty;

            if (HttpContext.Request.Form.Files != null)
            {
                var fileName = string.Empty;
                string PathDB = string.Empty;

                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                        var myUniqueFileName = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());

                        var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                        newFileName = myUniqueFileName + FileExtension;

                        fileName = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images") + $@"\{newFileName}";
                        PathDB = "images/" + newFileName;

                        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(fs);
                            fs.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            _db.Update(album);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return View("Index");

        }
```

The album Id in which the images are uploaded is passed into the method. I need to get this album Id, as well as image path (do I need image name as well?) into the database. How do I do that?

Also, is

`public List<Image> Image { get; set; }`

in the album class a correct way of storing images?

Comment: in your database you need to define column with type varbinary(max) and in c# for passing your image to database you need to convert the read image to array of  byte[]

Comment: you need to update or create album.id . save the file name & the album.Id in db.Image

Answer (score 0):

u can try this for filepath

```
string filepath=Path.GetFullPath(file)
```

and for filenam

```
string name=Path.GetFileName(file)
imagepath=filepath+name;
```

and for inserting it into database

```cs
 {
                    string sql = "insert into tablename values(@id,@AlbumId,@imagepath)";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
 {     
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumId", albumid);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagepath",imagepath);
 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 con.Close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@m1547,

[@marcelo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56076527/11480716) should put you in the right direction, implementation-wise. Just a couple of things to note on top of that would be:

- When store the image in a folder, rename it to a GUID instead of the original
  filename of the image. This will allow you to store two images where the original image filename is the same.  t
- Update your SQL schema to include the following columns:

  - GUID of the image (that your program sets),
  - Original filename (useful when display the image on screen to the user),
  - Folder path (where the physical file exists in the server),
  - Album path (in the case where your albums are only virtual albums, otherwise your folder path should already take care of this in the case where you are creating physical folders representing albums)

Hope this helps.